# PhpStorm does not sync files generated by Webpack with the server

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I have Webpack running which compiles my code to a bundle, such that change to a file `a.js` will trigger Webpack to recompile the whole project to another file called `bundle.js` which is roughly 150kb.

The issue is that although PhpStorm (2017.2) is configured to upload local changes to the server, it doesn't do so. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Since this file is generated outside of the IDE (not by File Watcher etc) .. it's considered "an external change". Is your Deployment configured to automatically upload them as well? *(that's of course, if we are talking about automatic upload and not manual here)*

Comment: @LazyOne Enabling `Upload external changes` doesn't solve this issue entirely because PhpStorm will try to upload after `Ctrl+S` but before the file compiled completely and in result it will not upload at all. Enabling to upload `Always` does not solve this issue either. But it does upload when I press `Ctrl+S` after the compilation completed–however waiting on compilation is troublesome.

Comment: Try using File Watcher then (to run Webpack compilation). If you specify what path to refresh (what file was generated/modified in the end) .. it will also treat that file as locally modified.

Comment: @LazyOne That partially solves the issue, partially because PhpStorm will report `Automatic upload: check for related changes from File Watchers took too much time and was cancelled.`, however most of the time the file will be uploaded despite the check was cancelled.